# How to call my external class within the program on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried to import a class I was provided by my lecturer within eclipse and I understand that I have to change the Java build path -> Library -> Add external Class folder option.

However, when I try to import the class within my source program I get the following error:

"The import lec cannot be resolved"

Using the following previous solution:
[How to Use External Class Files in an Eclipse Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172916/how-to-use-external-class-files-in-an-eclipse-project)

Thanks very much guys

Answer (score 0):

Here's another easy approach. With package explorer,

- create a folder `lib` in your project (or with any other name)
- copy the library to that folder (physically)
- right click the lib file, selects Build Path -> Add to Build Path

---

Regarding your comments:

- You've added the `lib` folder to your build path *as a new source folder*. Revert that and add *the jar file inside the folder*.
- Then, import the classes from a java package. Assuming, you have a folder `lib` that contains a file `mylib.jar` and this jar has a package `com.example` and you need the class `App` from that package, then the import statement in your java source file is `import com.example.App;`

Comment: I've tried that however it did not make any difference. However it did make a new package however the class file is not inside it any longer. I've physically copied it over as well.

Comment: The thing is I was only given a single class file with Javadocs and was told to just put in my project folder. I understand that I should put it inside a Jar file but have no clue how to do that exactly because my experience is quiet limited. Thanks once again for the help thus far

Comment: Ah, OK - so just for the class - switch to *Navigator View* (or use the windows explorer or equivalent) and locate the `bin` folder in your project (it's hidden from package explorer view!). That's where you have to store your class. Pay attention to the *fully qualified.classname*: Like if the class is named `com.example.MyClass`, then it has to be stored as `<project-folder>/bin/com/example/MyClass.class`. Hope it helps!